# Sharing data between my other apps

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am going to have database into my application. and i would like to know is it possible to share the same Db for Other apps we build.

Please let me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

NO WAY because every App running in its own sandbox.

[image: App Sandbox]

Please check the documentation here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheiOSEnvironment/TheiOSEnvironment.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH9-SW1

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. even if i know the db name and the app contains db is my own app and the other apps which is going to use that db is also my app. is not it possible even in this situtaion? pls let me knwo

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to share your Databases with multiple application,
You have a centralize dataBase and then you create webServices to access them.
Webservices will be linked with that dataBase and different Application can use the same webService to access the dataBase.

but if your App itself have a db then Shiny is correct.
You cannot share that DB with other Apps.